# File.Exists() returns false for some files under Program Files

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I thought it was due to some permission issue, but that does not seem to be the case. The file has "Read & Execute, Read" permissions for "Users", and "Full control" for "Administrators" and "SYSTEM". Can there be other reasons why `File.Exists()` returns `false`?

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

PS: I did not think the code was important, so I did not type the code, but if that is the rule, here is the text version of the code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe";
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = Path.GetFileName(app);
        psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(app);
        Process.Start(psi);
    }
```

Anyway, there seems to be a weird behaviour of pasting path in Visual Studio. If I use "Copy as path" in File Explorer and paste it into an empty string, VS removes the space between `Files` and `(x86)`.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. You should post the code as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your file-system, there's a *space* between `Files` and `(x86)`. You don't have that in the string you're using to get at the file, so it should be changed to:

```
var app = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe";
//                          ^
//                      need this
```

---

In terms of your statement that:

> Anyway, there seems to be a weird behaviour of pasting path in Visual Studio. If I use "Copy as path" in File Explorer and paste it into an empty string, VS removes the space between `Files` and `(x86)`.

That's almost certainly down to auto-formatting, which is done on paste among other things (though you can disable it, or use <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> to back up, since it appears to paste and *then* format).

Since you paste a `"quoted thing"` inside quotes to end up with `""quoted thing""`, the `quoted thing` bit is now *outside* quotes and therefore subject to auto-formatting.

Had you copied the file name *without* the quotes, or copied it with the quotes but pasted to a *non-quoted area,* I suspect it would have been put in unmodified (as a quoted string).

Comment: There seems to be a strange bug in Visual Studio. I used Shift+right click on the EXE, and chose "Copy as path". I pasted it into an existing quote `""`. Then, VS made it `""C:\Program Files(x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe""`, removing the space between `s` and `(`. I wonder why.

Comment: @DamnVegetables, see the update as to why that's happening.

Comment: Yeah, come to think of it, probably it thought the `Files ()` a function call. Of course, I did not intend to put a quoted string inside a quoted string; this is just what usually happens because when copying a file path, it has quotation marks. I often then remove the duplicate quotes.

Comment: @DamnVegetables: as well as pasting to an area not surrounded by quotes, you could also select the `""` before pasting. That will overwrite the quotes with the quoted filename and probably prevent auto-format from kicking in.